# Is this a counterexample to show that the image of a hausdorff space under a continuous map ist not Hausdorf anymore?

Tags: continuity

I have the following problem:

> I need to prove or give a counterexample for the following claim: The image of a Hausdorff space under a continuous map is Hausdorff.

I claimed that this is wrong and I gave the following example. Take $$f:\Bbb{R}_d\rightarrow \Bbb{R}_t;\,\,\,x\mapsto x$$ where $d$ is the discrete topology and $t$ the trivial one. This map is clearly continuous and the domain is Hausdorff. But then $f(\Bbb{R})$ is not Hausdorff anymore in the trivial topology.

Now I'm not sure if this works as a counterexample. Could someone maybe take a look?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your example works fine.

Comment: perfect thanks!